# How to save sorted column property and reapply on refresh?

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid

I have a grid that when I apply a descending sort it functions perfectly.  When I go to refresh the grid, though, the items default to ascending order.  How do I save the column's descending order property so that I can apply it back once a refresh has been completed?